# export 'default' (reexported as 'Modal') was not found in './Modal

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Why am I getting the following WARNING from Storybook:

```
WARNING in ./src/components/index.js 24:0-65
"export 'default' (reexported as 'Modal') was not found in './Modal'
```

**./src/components/index.js 24**

```
export { default as Modal, ModalNew, ModalVideo } from './Modal';
```

**./src/components/Modal/index.js**

```
export { default as ModalNew } from './ModalNew';
export { default as ModalAdapter } from './ModalAdapter';
export { default as ModalVideo } from './ModalVideo';
```

**./src/components/Modal/ModalNew.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import StyledModal from './StyledModal';
import Header from './Header';
import Body from './Body';

const ModalNew = ({
  children,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <StyledModal {...rest}>
    {children}
  </StyledModal>
);

ModalNew.Header = Header;
ModalNew.Body = Body;

ModalNew.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default ModalNew;
```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans appreciate the reply/help. I'm not sure I'm following the question/recommendation. Would you mind posting an answer on how one could resolve this issue? thanks

Comment: Thanks, updating to `export * from './Modal'; did the trick. Feel free to leave this as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again

Comment: answer written. But do read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export, this is elementary modern JS, not "React", so understanding this JS functionality if you're working with import/export statements is pretty worthwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default` is a very special word when it comes to JS modules, with the rule being that you *cannot* import a default if the module you're importing from doesn't *export* a default, using `export default ...`.

So in the code you're showing, `index.js` is importing defaults that don't exist:

```
export { default as Modal, ModalNew, ModalVideo } from './Modal';
```

is equivalent to:

```
import { default as Modal, ModalNew, ModalVideo } from './Modal';
export { Modal, ModalNew, ModalVideo };
```

but if we look at your Modal code, we see:

```
export { default as ModalNew } from './ModalNew';
export { default as ModalAdapter } from './ModalAdapter';
export { default as ModalVideo } from './ModalVideo';
```

which shows three named exports, and not a single `export default`. To import those, literally do that:

```
export { Modal, ModalNew, ModalVideo } from './Modal';
```

or, even shorter:

```
export * from './Modal';
```

And of course it's a good idea to make sure that `ModalNew`, `ModalAdapter`, and `ModalVideo` don't use default exports but instead export named entities too, so that your `Modal` code doesn't need to do weird default aliassing either, but you can just say:

```
export * from './ModalNew';
export * from './ModalAdapter';
export * from './ModalVideo';
```

Comment: There's a similar issue here where the * export works, but the named exports throw an error. Any idea why that might be? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920642/typescript-warning-export-reexported-as-was-not-found-possible-exports

Comment: That does not look like your question? So: post a new question with the actual error you get, after [searching for that specific error](/help/how-to-ask), of course. In terms of spec-compliant syntax, this is how it works, so if there's an incompletion in the answer I'll be happy to update it, but comments are not for new questions.