# TypeScript Warning: Export, reexported as, was not found (possible exports)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With this folder structure

```
├──components/
|  └─Employee/
|    └─employee.tsx
|    └─index.ts
|  └─app.tsx
```

I am exporting a type and a component

#### employee.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export type EmployeeState = {
  Name: string
  EmployeeId: number
}

type EmployeeProps = {
  employees: EmployeeState[]
}

export const Employee: FC<EmployeeProps> = ({ employees }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
    {
      employees.map((employee) => (
        <li key={employee.EmployeeId}>
          <h2>{employee.Name}</h2>
        </li>
      ))
    }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

And then exporting from `index.ts` on the `Employee` folder

#### index.ts

```
export { EmployeeState, Employee } from './employee'
```

When I try to import from `app.tsx`

#### app.tsx

```
...
import { EmployeeState, Employee } from '@components/Employee'
...
```

I get this warning from TypeScript:

```
WARNING in ../src/components/Employee/index.ts 4:0-53
`export 'EmployeeState' (reexported as 'EmployeeState') was not found in './employee' (possible exports: Employee)`
```

---

I was able to fix the warning by making this change:

#### Employee/index.ts

**Old**:

```
export { EmployeeState, Employee } from './employee'
```

**New**:

```
export * from './employee'
```

But I still do not understand why it would not work the other way around.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just have `employee.tsx` in your `components` directory and omit the `Employee` directory with its `index.ts` file?

Comment: Also, is that warning actually coming from TypeScript's `tsc` and not Webpack or Babel or Rollup?

Comment: @Dai,  because I am also adding employee.styles.tsx and want to have all in a folder and do from `@component/Employee` as opposed  to `@components/Employee/employee`. Yeah not to sure if the error comes from Webpack to be honest

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I also had this issue and after some more digging found this GitHub Issue which goes into detail if interested: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7378#issuecomment-683894656

Either way the solution is that your `type` needs to be exported differently. Updating your code to the following should fix your issue.

```js
export { Employee } from './employee'
export type { EmployeeState } from './employee'
```

If you care to read more about the how and why behind this, here is a good article: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/leveraging-type-only-imports-and-exports-with-typescript-3-8-5c1be8bd17fb

Comment: One could also do this: `export { Employee, type EmployeeState } from './employee'`

Comment: Thanks @bmacher, I haven't tried that but I like how clean it is.

Comment: This has always worked for me too, but in this one example I have it causes the same error to now appear twice 

Answer (score -3):

Simple way -
delete node_modules and run
npm install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).